# Given a % of change and the resulting value after the change, how do you calculate the original value?

Tags: linear-algebra, percentages

Given a % of change and the resulting value after the change, how do you calculate the original value?

For example, X increased by 50% = 150. In this case we can easily use guess and check to see that X = 100, but how do you calculate this given any percentage of change and any resulting value?

I though this formula should work, but it does not. As you can see my algebra is quite rusty, so maybe you can help.

```
start = x
percentage of change = p
resulting value = r

x * (p / 100) + x = r
```

Which can be simplified to

```
2(p / 100)x = r
```

which is equivalent to

```
x = r / 2(p / 100)
```

But when I check my work, this is wrong:

```
100 = 150 / 2(50 / 100)
100 = 150 / 2(.5)
100 = 150 / 1
100 = 150
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** If a number $x$ changes by $p$ percent, the resulting value is $\left(1+\frac{p}{100}\right)x$.

So the basic equation you have to solve is $\left(1+\frac{p}{100}\right)x =r$.

Your expression "2(p/100)x" is incorrect.

Comment: Ok, thanks. So now I need to rework this equation to have x by itself in on one side of the equal sign.

Comment: Yes. Just divide both sides by the parenthesized expression.

Comment: For example: Suppose you are told that a number increased by 20% and the result was 48. Then the original number must have been 48/1.20, which is 40.

Comment: It also works if $p$ is negative. Suppose you are told that a number *decreased* by 20% and the result was 48. Then the original number must have been 48/0.80, which is 60. Here the divisor 0.80 is 1+(-20/100).

Comment: Yes! The formula is working! My secret experiment can continue! Mwahahah!